# MUI DatePicker Button Missing anchorEl

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have the following component but when the date picker opens up I see an error in the console about a missing `anchorEl`. I am not sure where I would assign that.

```
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Date"
        open={datePickerOpen}
        renderInput={(params) => {
          const currentDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(
            params.inputProps ? new Date(params.inputProps.value) : new Date()
          );

          return (
            <div ref={params.ref}>
              <input
                disabled={params.disabled}
                style={{ display: 'none' }}
                value={params.inputProps?.value}
                onChange={params.onChange}
                {...params.inputProps}
              />
              <button className="calendar-date-picker" onClick={() => toggleDatePicker()}>
                {currentDate.toFormat(`MMM dd, yyyy`)}
                <ArrowDropDownIcon sx={DatePickerDownArrowSx} />
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        }}
        value={new Date()}
        views={['month', 'day']}
        onChange={(newValue: Date | null) => handleDateChange(newValue)}
        onClose={() => toggleDatePicker()}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Could you include the error message?  Is there a possibility of you including a reproduction in something like codesandbox or stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is related to the missing reference to the element needed to let the popover appear. The popover should appear when clicking on the input, by default, but you can customize this behavior. In the code I can not see the `inputRef` property. Note that this key is not part of the `inputProps`, basically you have this `{ inputRef, inputProps, InputProps }` as a parameter of the `renderInput` property related function.

I think you should add the `ref` property, something like

```
<input
  disabled={params.disabled}
  style={{ display: 'none' }}
  value={params.inputProps?.value}
  onChange={params.onChange}
  ref={params.inputRef}
  {...params.inputProps}
/>
```

Check this link for more information

https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#custom-input-component

Check also the line about `<div ref={params.ref}>`, probably there is no `ref` key in the `params` object. Probably what you wanted is `<div ref={params.inputRef}>`, or something like that.

Comment: So I needed to to change the div ref to `<div ref={params.inputRef}>` and that fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Above is one solution, but your specific issue lies in the `anchorEl`, that is declared on the PopoverProps, ie. what the popover is attached to i.e. a current ref.

```
<DatePicker
 ...etc
   PopoverProps={{
     anchorEl: () => anchorElRef.current
   }}
>
</DatePicker>
```